# Sqoop bash script can not read records even MapReduce job finished successfully?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Following is the script to invoke `Sqoop` import:

```
for table in ${mysql_biz_sso_tables}; do
    ${SQOOP_HOME}/bin/sqoop-import \
    --username ${mysql_biz_user} \
    --password ${mysql_biz_password} \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://${mysql_biz_host}/${mysql_biz_sso_db} \
    --direct \
    --autoreset-to-one-mapper \
    -m 1 \
    --append \
    --table ${table} \
    --target-dir ${hdfs_target_dir} 
done
```

And following is the logs from `Hadoop`:

```
16/02/17 18:15:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1455506711073_0014
completed successfully 16/02/17 18:15:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
    Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=1
            Map output records=0
            Input split bytes=87
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=31
            CPU time spent (ms)=1320
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=160542720
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=890945536
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=201326592
    File Input Format Counters
            Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters
            Bytes Written=0 16/02/17 18:15:56 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase:  Transferred 0 bytes in  20.4039 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
```

Is there any configuration for `Sqoop` caused the failure? I'm newly on `Sqoop`, anybody can help?